# What is ServiceBase.ServiceHandle? Any examples?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am working in a service that watches the file system for a modification/addition/removal of anything inside a folder. As I started to implement it, I'd met this property, inside the `ServiceBase` class, `ServiceBase.ServiceHandle`.
What is this used for?
What can I achieve with it?
I tried googling about it, but found little more than the MSDN site told me already.
Do someone know some example or a tutorial how to use it?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ServiceBase.ServiceHandle` is the system handle used to update the service's status in the Services control panel.  It is the same handle returned by the Win32 [`RegisterServiceCtrlHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685054%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

All services have the responsibility of updating their status.  In unmanaged services, such as those created in C++, this was the responsibility of the developer.  You'd pass the handle and the updated status (e.g., START_PENDING, RUNNING, STOPPED) as input to the Win32 [`SetServiceStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function when the status changed.

Even in managed services, such as those created with C#, the developer is still responsible for updating the status; it's just that the `ServiceBase` class performs all of the status updates for you.

In short, I would say that this handle is completely unnecessary for managed services that inherit from `ServiceBase.`